# Building where statement dyamically

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list where I wish to add items to dyanmically in the where clause if I dont have a user id at present the linq will fall over.

```
List<ScreenermissionsForSearch> _screen = new List<ScreenermissionsForSearch>();
_screen= _security.GetScreenermissionsForSearch();

gridControl1.DataSource = _screen.Where(w => w.Code ==
Convert.ToInt32(txtUserId.Text) || w.ScreenName ==dbscreenanme.Text).ToList();

this.gridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
this.gridView1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
```

So I need some wway of being able to append to the where clause checking if the string is null or not first or am I not doing this right in the frist place?.

Edit to show clairty Here it is just listing them all when i want it to only show provider if user id is empty.

[image]

It works here and shows fine as should do but its not for the other condition
[image]

**New Code**

```
 _screen= _security.GetScreenermissionsForSearch();
        gridControl1.DataSource = _screen.Where(w => string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserId.Text)  || w.ScreenName == dbscreenanme.Text).ToList();
        this.gridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
        this.gridView1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this condition to where clause `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserId.Text)` and change the condition;

```
gridControl1.DataSource = _screen.Where(w =>
    (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUserId.Text) || w.Code == Convert.ToInt32(txtUserId.Text)) &&
    w.ScreenName == dbscreenanme.Text)).ToList();
```

If you don't want to get result when parsing is failed try following code;

```
gridControl1.DataSource = _screen.Where(w =>
    w.Code == int.TryParse(txtUserId.Text,out var val) ? val : -1 &&
    w.ScreenName == dbscreenanme.Text)).ToList();
var entity = Context.Parents.Include(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Say used id =1 and i send the table name provider which I no there is a user there it fails and doesnt display it i need it to display either case.

Comment: please see my screen shots above.

Comment: That works but if its option 0 in the dropdown i want them to just list them all unless the user Id matches if that makes since

Comment: Apply the same logic as txtUserId.

Comment: thanks very much and such a classic film to have a reference off always reminds me the little guy can succeed in life.

Comment: Sorry but null or empty does not work is their another syntax I can use for the combo box obv item 0 is please select

Comment: You shouldn't compare IsNullOrEmpty for combo. Compare it with default value like "(dbscreenanme.Text == "0" || w.ScreenName == dbscreenanme.Text)"